# How to create a navigation view without navigationdrawer

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

i need to create a navigation view that user can use to navigate to different activities/fragments but i do not want to achieve this using navigation drawer. i want a simple horizontal bar of icons and some text below them as shown in the image below(screenshot is attached).i have tried searching it but do not know the exact terminology for it i.e. what it is called in android. any link to documentation or any link to video tutorials or any thing else  that can help me search this on the internet will be very useful [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd9g6.png)

Comment: you can achieve this by linear layout with horizontal orientation and then you can use the intent for calling a particular activity.

Comment: Thanks.... can i also use a recycler view with horizontal orientation because i need to show a lot of categories?